# resolveActivity - returns com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity in case of no default app set

Tags: android, android-intent

As per the android documentation -

resolveActivity - Returns a ResolveInfo object containing the final activity intent that was determined to be the best action. Returns null if no matching activity was found. If multiple matching activities are found and there is no default set, returns a ResolveInfo object containing something else, such as the activity resolver (e.g. com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity ).

But the problem is activity resolver can differ based on OEM in case of multiple matching activities are found and there is no default set.

How to ensure that there is no default is set by user for particular implicit intent?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question? I have the same problem and I want to receive the first activity that matches my action, but all I receive is com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity

Comment: `queryIntentActivities()` method worked for me (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int))